# Reading a label VBA - Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with VBA programming. I want to read the text of a label that represents the interpolation of a curve. 
I used this code:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Numero_serie).Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Select

Selection.NumberFormat = "0.000000"

' estrae dall'etichetta di una interpolazione i coefficienti e li ricopia in celle scelte dall'utente
Dim s, x3, x2, x, c, R As Double
Dim i1, i2, i3, f1, f2, f3, ic, fc

s = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Numero_serie).Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text
f4 = InStr(s, "x4")
x4 = Val(Replace(Mid(s, i4, f4 - i4), ",", "."))
Worksheets("Interpola").Range("B" & 6) = s
```

The code works but it writes in B6 always the same label even if I change the number format to "0.0000". 
Thanks for your attention, 
Andrea

Comment: Try changing the formatting of B6.

Comment: It's the same. it seems that changing the numberformat i am changing just the label that i see. But when i acceed in it it's always the same. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try changing the formatting of B6 cell in Excel to "Text".

Comment: No way. I tried also to declare s as string but nothing. I cant represent my label changing the number format. There must be a mistake but i cant find it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ch As ChartObject
Dim s As String

Set ws = Worksheets("Interpola")
Set ch = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1")
ch.Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Numero_serie).Trendlines(1).DataLabel.NumberFormat = "0.0000"
s = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Numero_serie).Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text
ws.Range("B6").Value = s
```

**Note** - Change "Chart 1" to the name of your chart.

This worked for me when I changed the `NumberFormat` from "0.000000" to "0.0000".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, it works fine. I think the problem was that:

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Numero_serie).Trendlines(1).DataLabel.NumberFormat = "0.0000"
```

is different from

```
thisActiveChart.SeriesCollection(Numero_serie).Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Select
Selection.NumberFormat="0.0000"
```

I don't know why but now everything works well.
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry im new..i accepted your anwer. it's correct now? thanks

Comment: Yes it is, thank you. Accepting the correct answer makes it easier for future viewers to see what worked. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please come back anytime with questions.